# Getting a view's listener

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get the listener that is attached to a view if it exists ? for example if  i have a view i would like to get the listener that is listening to that view if there exists one

Comment: Maybe clarify what you mean by "view"? A JFrame, a complete GUI that's being run? Do you have control of the objects in your source code?

Comment: a View as an object created from the android View class developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method I could find is [View.getOnFocusChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getOnFocusChangeListener%28%29). So a standard-library `View` will only tell you about its `OnFocusChangeListener`; for other listeners, no such getters are part of the class, so if you want to introduce those, you may have to subclass View.

Also, there are some methods that tell you whether a specific type of listener is attached to the `View` without returning the listener, for example whether a [drag event listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchDragEvent%28android.view.DragEvent%29), an [on click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) or an [on long click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performLongClick%28%29) is attached to the `View`. Note: some of these methods may have side effects, check the docs on that.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you take the OnClickListener for instance, it has protected access in View. Only a subclass could grant public access to the Listener fields, but no framework class does. On the other hand, you have the full responsibility to set the Listener in the first place, so you can set up your own data structures to track that information, if necessary.